# how do I edit the Mondodb.conf file

Tags: mongodb

How do I edit the mongodb.conf file?

I want to change the bind_ip from `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0`.

I have tried `sudo mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0`
I have tried manually editing the file (in a text editor), but it won't let me save.
I have tried changing the permissions of the file, yet I still can not save.

I didn't create a mongodb.conf file either, so I'm not sure why it was automatically set up as 127.0.0.1

I'm using Ubuntu.

I've tried searching around but I haven't had any luck.

All suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both the */etc/mongod.conf* and */var/log/mongodb/mongob.log* files are write restricted to super users. Your standard login account is not allowed to directly modify them.

To edit the mongod.conf file , open a terminal and run the following command (sudo will ask you for **your** password):

```
gksudo gedit /etc/mongod.conf
```

Edit the file to add 0.0.0.0 (or just comment the line out ), save the mongodb.conf file.

In addition mongod is a service on ubuntu so you'll need to run following command in the terminal to restart it to read the new config:

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

*You can read about sudo [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)*

Comment: I am getting `-bash: gksudo: command not found`

Comment: what about windows server? I don't have sudo

Answer (score 2):

If you're on windows and are wondering how to edit the config file.

1. Open the file
2. Edit the cfg file however you want.
3. Save as and save it to another folder somewhere else
4. Copy/cut and past the file back into the bin folder and accept admin permission
5. Go to windows services and stop->start/restart the MongoDB server service.

Done

Answer (score 1):

trying using your specified `mongodb.conf` to mongo deamon

use following command to start the mongod daemon

```
mongod -f <file-locattion>/mongodb.conf
```

and in your `mongodb.conf` file add following

```
    bind_ip=<your-pref-ip>
   <rest of setting -such as data-folder etc>
```

Comment: Hey, I get this error:

~$ mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf
all output going to: /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
can't open [/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log] for log file: errno:13 Permission denied
Sun May 26 20:46:11 dbexit:

Comment: did you stopped the previous running mongodb instance ? and also check for 'data' directory set and there check for mongod.lock. if it some KB then delete this and start the new instance with your given command

Answer (score -1):

using aws ubuntu instance i ssh to my instance using putty navigate to the file directory and
i used the command

> sudo pico mongodb.conf

the file opened and i edited my file then saved it
by following onscreen commands